# How does the command "flutter create" work?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to know how do all the files are generated when I execute `flutter create <app_name>` command.

I've looked through [flutter/flutter repository](https://github.com/flutter/flutter) and [flutter/engine repository](https://github.com/flutter/engine) but couldn't find the answer.
I would like to customize the codes of `lib/main.dart` file when I create a new app, so I want to know where are the auto-generated files come from. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Here? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/flutter_tools/templates/app

Comment: @julemand101 just asking, where are the commands such as `create` in the repo?

Comment: Create: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/commands/create.dart . The tool are mainly running this file which then points to all sub commands: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/executable.dart

Comment: @julemand101 thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a Flutter developer so I am not that strong into how the project are organized. But by searching around I found the following package which seem to be the base of the Flutter tool:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/flutter_tools

You can e.g. find the examples for `flutter create` here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/flutter_tools/templates/app

The create command itself is defined here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/commands/create.dart

And the Flutter tool are mainly running this file which then points out to all sub commands: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/executable.dart